# use 1 function instead of 3 functions in java

Tags: java

Below is a copy of my homework, I already had it graded dont worry! Feedback was "You do not need 3 different functions to read the input: use the same function 3 times instead". Can someone show me this? I am brand new at Java and would really like to understand before moving forward.

```
/*
*/
package numbers;

/**
 */
import javax.swing.*;
public class Numbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declare variables
    float number1 = 0, number2 = 0, number3 = 0, smallest = 0, largest = 0, 
            average, output;
    int count = 0;
    while (count< 3) {
        count += 1;

         //Call Input method    
         number1 = firstNumber();
         count+=1;
         number2 = secondNumber();
         count+=1;
         number3 = thirdNumber();

        //Method to find the largest and smallest numbers
        largest = max(number1, number2, number3);
        smallest = min(number1, number2, number3);

    }
         //Methods to calculate average and display output messages
         average = mean(number1, number2, number3);
         results(largest, smallest, average);

        //Warning messages regarding size of input numbers 
        if (smallest > 50){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"WARNING, YOUR NUMBERS ARE ALL "
                + "OVER 50!");
        }
        if (largest < 50){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"WARNING ALL YOUR NUMBERS ARE "
                + "UNDER 50!");
        }
 } 
 /*
 * Method for Data Input
 */
public static float firstNumber() {
    float firstNumber = Float.parseFloat (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your "
            + "first number: "));
    return firstNumber;
}
public static float secondNumber() {
    float secondNumber = Float.parseFloat (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your "
            + "second number: "));
    return secondNumber;
}
public static float thirdNumber() {
    float thirdNumber = Float.parseFloat (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your "
            + "third and final number: "));
    return thirdNumber;
}

 /*
 * Method for maximum calculation
 */
public static float max(float firstNumber, float secondNumber, float thirdNumber) {
   float maxValue;
   if ((firstNumber >= secondNumber) && (firstNumber >= thirdNumber))
      maxValue = firstNumber;
   else if ((firstNumber <= secondNumber) && (secondNumber >= thirdNumber))
      maxValue = secondNumber;
   else
       maxValue = thirdNumber;
   return maxValue;
 }
 /*
 * Method for minimum calculation
 */
public static float min(float firstNumber, float secondNumber, float thirdNumber) {
   float minValue;
   if ((firstNumber <= secondNumber) && (firstNumber <= thirdNumber))
      minValue = firstNumber;
   else if ((firstNumber >= secondNumber) && (secondNumber <= thirdNumber))
      minValue = secondNumber;
   else
       minValue = thirdNumber;
   return minValue;
}
/*
 * Method for average calculation
 */
public static float mean(float firstNumber, float secondNumber, float thirdNumber){
   float average;
   average = ((firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber)/3);
   return average;
}
/*
 * Method for display
 */
public static void results(float maxValue, float minValue, float average){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The largest of your input "
                + "numbers is: " + maxValue+ ". " + "The smallest of your input "
                + "numbers is: " + minValue+". " + "And, the average of your input "
                + "numbers is: " +average);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because regardless of whether or not you've already handed this in, it's still a `"do my work for me"` type question. Please ask a specific question about what confuses you, not just a requirement and a code dump.

Comment: The three methods do exactly the same thing. The only difference between them is a small part of the message prompted to the user. So why not use a single method, and pass this small part of the message as argument to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the string as a Param to the function and concatenate it with the complete string as.

```
public static float getNumber(String str) {
float number = Float.parseFloat (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your "
        + str+": "));
return number;
}
```

and then call it as.

```
     number1 = getNumber("first number");
     count+=1;
     number2 = getNumber("second number");
     count+=1;
     number3 = getNumber("third and final number");
```

Mark as right if it works for you.
:)

Answer (score 2):

You could collapse all your "get a number" methods into one that takes a parameter.

```
public static float getNumber(String promptText) {

     return Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(promptText));
}
```

Using this you would simply put in your main method.

```
float number1 = getNumber("Enter your First Number");
```